# How to turn off Google Reminders sync for Android?

Tags: sync, google

I closed the Google sync option, but it appears in the notification bar. So I must turn off manually every time.

Comment: Closed means you turned off? What version of Android you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable sync from accounts option.

Go to `settings -> Accounts -> select google -> select gmail account -> unselect all options`

Comment: I did as you told me,it didn't work.